# How can you store an array of protocols with associated types in Swift without using Any?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, type-erasure

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
protocol StateType { }

struct DogState: StateType { }

struct CatState: StateType { }

protocol Action {
    associatedType ST
    func process() -> ST
}

struct DogAction {
    func process() -> DogState { return DogState() }
}

struct CatAction {
    func process() -> CatState { return CatState() }
}

let actions = [DogAction(), CatAction()]

actions.forEach {
    $0.process()
}
```

I've tried fooling around with type-erasure but I can't get past the issue of not being able to create heterogeneous arrays.

```
struct AnyActionProtocol<A: Action, ST: StateType>: Action  where A.StateType == ST {
    let action: A

    init(_ action: A) {
        self.action = action
    }

    func process() -> ST {
        return action.process()
    }
}

let dap = AnyActionProtocol<DogAction, DogState>(DogAction())
let cap = AnyActionProtocol<CatAction, CatState>(CatAction())
```

When I try this, the error I get is Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to [Any] which is something I'm trying to avoid.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Rather than trying to find a complex solution to your current coding issue (which doesn't even exist, since you'd need to store heterogenous elements in an array), you should try to rethink your proposed solution to the real-world problem you are trying to solve. There most certainly is a way to solve the problem in Swift, but it might not be via protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PATs are usually complex and do not involve an easier solution. I would suggest you come up with some simpler design for your problem. The problem with your method is actually having PAT and nested protocols and trying to make them work together.

Even if you type erase `Action` to some type like `AnyAction`, these two different types `DogAction` and `CatAction` again produce different types and you cannot intermix them inside the array. What you can possibly do is have two type erasures, one for `Action` and other for `StateType`. When you wrap `CatAction` or `DogAction` inside `AnyAction` both of them would then wrap in type erase state to `AnyState`.

Here is one example you could approach this type erasing both the protocols,

```
protocol StateType { }

struct DogState: StateType { }

struct CatState: StateType { }

protocol Action {
    associatedtype ST: StateType
    func process() -> ST
}

struct DogAction: Action {
    func process() -> DogState { return DogState() }
}

struct CatAction: Action {
    func process() -> CatState { return CatState() }
}

struct AnyState: StateType {
    let state: StateType

    init(_ state: StateType) {
        self.state = state
    }
}


struct AnyAction: Action {
    typealias ST = AnyState

    let processor: () -> AnyState

    init<T: Action>(_ a: T)  {
        self.processor = {
            return AnyState(a.process())
        }
    }

    func process() -> AnyState {
        return processor()
    }
}


let cat = AnyAction(CatAction())
let dog = AnyAction(DogAction())

let actions = [cat, dog]

actions.forEach { action in
    action.process()
}
```

I still think that you should rethink your solution, this can get more complicated as your types increase.

Comment: My state types will increase but they will all follow this pattern. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Quick question...how do you handle an argument to the process function...something like this?

    func process(currentState: ST) -> ST